# Xcode 4.3 is not finding header files in /usr/include

Tags: c++, xcode

For some reason Xcode is saying it cannot find a header file which is located in /usr/include

As a test, I just put the include at the top of a hello world program. I can compile it fine with clang in the terminal, but in Xcode it still says it cannot find the header.

I tried adding /usr/include to the "Header Search Paths" in build settings, but it is still not finding it.

I am not sure what to do here. It seems like Xcode should automatically be looking in this directory in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in Xcode you build against a particular SDK. This gets passed as the `-isysroot` parameter and is prefaced to system includes. So instead of looking in `/usr/include`, you would be looking in a path like:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/
```

This would be for the 10.8 SDK under the default Xcode. You can find your current Xcode path using `xcode-select --print-path`.