# GCC not finding header files in /usr/local/include

Tags: c++, gcc, include, header-files

I've recently installed [libechonest](https://projects.kde.org/projects/playground/libs/libechonest) and all its dependencies, yet to include its header files (in `/usr/local/include/echonest/` I have to specify the whole path, i.e. `#include "/usr/local/include/echonest/Artist.h"` instead of just `#include <Artist.h>`:

```
alexcannon$ gcc -g -o geoEchoNest geoEchoNest.c -lechonest
geoEchoNest.c:6:10: fatal error: 'Artist.h' file not found
#include "Artist.h"
```

Why is this? According to the GCC docs it should look in `/usr/local/include` by default:

> GCC looks in several different places for headers. On a normal Unix system, if you do not >instruct it otherwise, it will look for headers requested with #include  in:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/include
> libdir/gcc/target/version/include
> /usr/target/include
> /usr/include
> ```

How can I fix it? I have the same problem for other libraries, e.g. I have to do `#include "/usr/local/include/QtCore/QDebug"` instead of `include <QDebug>` so it's not just an echonest issue.

Permissions for `/usr/local/include` are `drwxrwxr-x`. Here is my gcc info:

```
alexcannon$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-    include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.76) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

I searched and found lots of similar `#include` GCC questions, but the only one specifically dealing with issues finding files in `/usr/local/include` [was specific to XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697657/xcode-4-3-is-not-finding-header-files-in-usr-include).

Obviously let me know if you need any more info and as always thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The include path is not searched recursively, try this.

```
#include <echonest/Artist.h>
```

Comment: It would be an unmitigated disaster if it *would* be searched recursively... I just counted six different `error.h` in my `/usr/include`. :-D